# Using lines after readFile

Tags: haskell, readfile, lines

I'm trying to do some programming in Haskell. I'm trying to read a file and then put every line in the file in a list by using the line function. Here's the partial code:

```
file = "muh.rtr"
readTrack :: String -> Track
readTrack file =
    do      let defFile = readFile file
            let fileLines = lines defFile
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Parser.hs:22:39:
    Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `IO String'
    In the first argument of `lines', namely `defFile'
    In the expression: lines defFile
    In an equation for `fileLines': fileLines = lines defFile
```

I have been searching the Internet for hours now hoping to find some answers somewhere but I've not been so lucky so far.

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664050/works-in-ghci-but-not-when-loaded/12665589#12665589) I gave to someone who's getting the same error message as you.

Answer (score 9):

You probably wanted either something like this:

```
readTrack :: String -> IO Track
readTrack file = do defFile <- readFile file
                    let fileLines =  lines defFile
                    -- etc....
```

...or something like this:

```
readTrack :: String -> IO Track
readTrack file = do fileLines <- liftM lines (readFile file)
                    -- etc....
```

But what you really *should* do is stop, go find an introduction to the language such as [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), and spend some time reading it.

Feeding code consisting entirely of very simple errors into GHC and then posting the error message on Stack Overflow is not a good way to learn.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I lost my patience and posted this question here is because I have a deadline tomorrow and it's already late in the evening over here so I'm getting tired.
Anyway, it has to be "readTrack :: String -> Track" (I'm doing a little project that says I should implement the function like that)
Is there no other way be able to use "lines" with Track instead of IO Track?

Comment: @user1683526 I've seen this kind of comment ("I have an assignment due tomorrow and need fast answers") a couple of times, but never found it very convincing. Your poor planning isn't our responsibility. If you need to learn a thing to make progress, you need to learn it, whether you have a deadline for the progress or not.

Comment: @user1683526: If this is part of a homework assignment, then you have *much bigger problems* than one deadline. Both the question and your comment suggest you don't understand some very essential, basic concepts. You're not going to do very well in the course at this rate.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Perhaps it stems from a confusion of terminology - I think they were asked to write a function that reads tracks, by someone who would use the word read in the same sense as `read :: Read a => String -> a`, whereas user1683526 has interpreted it in the sense of `fmap read.readFile`. The instructor might not have covered any IO yet (I wouldn't teach IO until I'd done a fair bit of pure functional) and wasn't expecting the word read to be interpreted in this way.

Comment: @user1683526: you should probably read your homework assignment more critically.  Either your teacher made a serious mistake in writing it, or you have made a serious mistake in interpreting it.

Answer (score 6):

The type of `readFile` is

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

so you need to use `<-` to bind the result, and your function has to return `IO Track`.

```
readTrack :: String -> IO Track
readTrack file =
  do defFile <- readFile file
     let fileLines = lines defFile
     ...
```

I suggest reading a good tutorial on IO in Haskell, for example the [Input and Output chapter of Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).

Answer (score 5):

readFile return an `IO string`. That is, it is an IO computation that returns a string. This means that you need to use `<-` instead of `let` to "get" the string its returning.

```
 readTrack file =
    do
        defFile <- readFile file
        ...
```

You can use `let` to bind things that are not IO computations, such as the return value of lines, that is a regular string.

```
readTrack file =
    do
        defFile <- readFile file
        let fileLines = lines defFile
        ...
```

Finally, you need to return the value you might want to try something like

```
readTrack file =
    do
        defFile <- readFile file
        let fileLines = lines defFile
        fileLines --Doesn't actually work!
```

but unfortunately, since we are inside a "do" block and are trying to return a monadic computation, we need to send the fileLines back into the io monad (remember, out function returns `IO [String]`, not `String`!

```
readTrack file =
    do
        defFile <- readFile file
        let fileLines = lines defFile
        return fileLines
```

Note that the "return" here is *not* a return statement as would normaly be found in most languages and it should not be used in your pure functions.

All this might seem like a lot at first. I would suggest you stick to pure functions (without input and output / monads) until until you get a better hang on the language.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it like that -- you've run into the IO monad.  What you need to do is something like:

```
readTrack :: String -> IO Track
readTrack file = do
   defFile <- readFile file
   let fileLines = lines deffile
   ...
   return whatever
```

Think of `IO T` values as statements (as opposed to expressions) with return type `T`.  Because statements have side effects, but expressions don't, you can never turn a statement into an expression; the type system enforces this, which is why your type signature won't work.

Note the different assignment-like syntax in the `do` block:  in this example, the `foo <- bar` is used for `IO` operations, while the `let baz = quux` syntax is used for purely functional evaluation.    This is more fallout from using monadic I/O -- it makes more sense in the full generality of Haskell's polymorphic type system, but it's not necessarily bad to have a syntactic indicator of pure vs. side-effecting operations, either.

In general, it is good practice to try keeping most of your implementation in the purely functional realm:  implement your pure computation with regular functional methods, *then* describe your I/O operations in the `IO` monad.  It is a common novice mistake to write loops in the IO monad which would be more appropriate as list comprehensions or recursive functions.

Answer (score 3):

If your function is supposed to have type `readTrack :: String -> Track`, are you sure the String is a filename? Perhaps it's data - if so, don't use `readFile`. Write some sample data and test using that, eg

```
sampleData = "2 3\n1 30 234 45\n1 2 32 4\n5 3 4 23"
```

(The other question on SO about this homework didn't use file IO. I'll not link to it because you're in a crisis and might be tempted to copy, and in any case if you refuse to learn haskell at least I'll force you to improve your StackOverflow search skills! :) )

In any case I think you'll get more marks by solving the String problem than by solving the IO problem.

Delay the readFile issue until you've got the pure version working, otherwise you might end up writing most of your code in the IO monad which would be much more complex than necessary.

One you have a pure function `readTrack :: String -> Track`, you can do

```
readTrackFrom :: FilePath -> IO Track
readTrackFrom filename = fmap readTrack (readFile filename)
```

Now, `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so takes pure functions and lifts them to work in a different computational context like IO.

Since `IO` is a `Functor` (look it up tomorrow, not tonight), we're using it as the type `(String -> Track) -> IO String -> IO Track`. That's good because `readTrack :: String -> Track` and `(readFile filename) :: IO String`.

If you want to, you can then `>>= print` or `>>= writeFile newfilename` as you see fit.

Don't forget to add `deriving Show` after use `data Track =...`, but you don't need to if you're using `type Track = ....`.

Comment: @user1683526 I believe you've had this homework for more than a week. Start straight away next time - you'll have time to write a really _good_ solution, learn lots and iron out any difficulties. Haskell is a fabulous language to program in, but you have to learn a lot to use it effectively - think more, write less, but better.